# jQuery onClick preventDefault

Tags: jquery

I have a table of which I want to suppress the link clicks, because I need the links for other functionality.

The structure of the table is something like this:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Day</th><th>Event</th>
<tr class="DAY" id="DAY_0"><td>1-8-2013</td><td><a href="?tab=tabCalendar&dayEvent=DAY_0">Add Event</a></td></tr>
<tr class="DAY" id="DAY_1"><td>2-8-2013</td><td><a href="?tab=tabCalendar&dayEvent=DAY_1">Add Event</a></td></tr>
</table
```

my jquery code to try and block the  from refreshing the page, and showing the id is this

```
<script>
  $("a").click(
      function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Picked: '+ event.target.id.slice(4) );
      }
    );
  </script>
```

I have also tried the following

```
$(".DAY").click(function(){//to catch the class DAY.click()
```

and even

```
$("[id^=DAY]").click(function(){//to catch the id DAY*.click
```

however, none of these function did anything.

The versions I use are

```
jquery-1.9.1.js
jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simplest approach:

```
<script>
   $(".DAY").click(
      function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         alert('Picked: '+ $(this).attr('id').slice(4));
      }
   );
</script>
```

Answer (score 11):

Try to put the script in `DOM READY`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").on('click',function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('Picked: '+ $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').id.slice(4) );
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: what's the difference ?

Comment: so long as the script has run before you try and click something it wont make any difference. if the script runs before the elements exist in the dom it would error anyway.

Comment: You have to add the class DAY to the jquery selector: $("a.DAY"), to make it work properly

Comment: +1 for using .on() and being able of using a elements even with AJAX load, XD

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a").click(
      function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

          DATA = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id').slice(4);

        alert('Picked: ' + DATA);
      }
    );

});
```

This will get select the `ID` of the `a` you clicked. I've also created this as a jSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pAZeb/

Comment: in your jsfiddle, it works perfectly, in my page, a pure copy-paste, it doesn't. page refreshes and no alert is shown...

Comment: EDIT: changed a bit in the order of the code, and now it works. either this, or a problem with the cache of some sort...

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the `id` of the [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) `tr` of the clicked `a`

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Picked: '+ $(this).closest('tr').attr('id').slice(4) );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to modify to the following:

```
$("a").click(
function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Picked: ' + $(this).closest('tr').attr('id').slice(4));
});
```